# Call COM wituout COM interop dll

Tags: c#, com

I'm developing application that require send shortcut to desktop operation. I found only one way to implement it:

```
var shell = new IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell();
var shortcut = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(linkFileName);
shortcut.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath;
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
shortcut.Save();
```

It's working coreect, but Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll required.
My application require deployment throught one small exe file, I can't include any other files into package.

Is where a way to call COM without interop dll?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you can create a COM object in .NET without an interop library.  As long as they COM object implements [IDispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318520%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (which [WScript.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does) you can call methods and properties on it easily.

If you are using .NET 4, the dynamic type makes this very easy.  If not you'll have to use Reflection to call the methods, which will work but isn't nearly as pretty.

**.NET 4 with dynamic**

```
Type shellType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WScript.Shell");
dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellType);
dynamic shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(linkFileName);
shortcut.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath;
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
shortcut.Save();
```

**.NET 3.5 or earlier with Reflection**

```
Type shellType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WScript.Shell");
object shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellType);
object shortcut = shellType.InvokeMember("CreateShortcut",
      BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
      null, shell, new object[] { linkFileName });
Type shortcutType = shortcut.GetType();
shortcutType.InvokeMember("TargetPath",
      BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
      null, shortcut, new object[] { Application.ExecutablePath });
shortcutType.InvokeMember("WorkingDirectory",
      BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty, 
      null, shortcut, new object[] { Application.StartupPath });
shortcutType.InvokeMember("Save",
      BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
      null, shortcut, null);
```

Comment: I'm using DN 3.5 and can't use dynamic :(

Comment: You still need a reference to Microsoft.CSharp if you use the dynamic method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Microsoft utility called ILMerge, downloadable from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630), to merge the DLL into your exe.

There is a brief description on how to use it in [this article](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4504/merge-an-exe-and-a-dll-into-one-exe/)

Comment: This is not an acceptable solution. I don't belive into that tool.

Comment: @Viacheslav Could you elaborate on why ILMerge won't work for you? It is considered the standard .NET way to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, since ILMerge is unnaceptable for some reason.

C# includes the ability to interract with underlying COM and Windows DLLs.  You could write your own COM interop within the EXE.

Here is [an article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/com/article.php/c9065) describing how you can do this.

Comment: Please add this to the end of your previous answer.

Comment: @John - serious question - Why? I thought carefully about doing that and chose a separate answer.  It is a totally different and separate approach to answering the problem.